# What to do with an insignificant intercept in a GARCH model?

Tags: garch, intercept

I have fitted model to my data and estimated parameters both using R and Matlab. Here are my results:

```
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
mu     -0.000188    0.000386 -0.48707 0.626206
omega   0.000002    0.000002  0.87820 0.379837
alpha1  0.062080    0.019779  3.13870 0.001697
beta1   0.925053    0.021205 43.62490 0.000000
```

Do I have to reject both `mu` and `omega` parameters? Is it really that bad? Does my model not fit the data well at all? Or have I missunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons for keeping the intercept (like `mu` here) in conditional mean models even if it is not statistically significant. This has been discussed in several existing threads, e.g. ["When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model). However, @ChrisHaug might be right that *If you are looking at financial market data at a fairly high frequency (say, daily or higher), it's quite common to have insignificant mean return. In that context, the application is rarely long-term forecasting where fixing mean return = 0 would ruin the forecast, and doing so is a common practice.* In any case, if the mean is really small, then neither keeping it nor restricting it to zero should make a  considerable difference.

`omega` (the intercept of the conditional variance model) should be kept in the model for the following reasons.

1. **If** you force `omega=0` and get `alpha+beta<1` (by design of the estimation procedure that restricts the parameters to a stationary region defined by `alpha+beta<1`), **then** your model implies the conditional variance is decreasing over time, which is generally undesirable.
2. **If** you force `omega=0` and also explicitly force `alpha+beta=1`, **then** you end up with an EWMA estimator of the conditional variance, and the conditional variance is a random walk (which again might be undesirable).
3. Also, note that testing for `omega=0` is testing a hypothesis that the parameter is on the boundary of the space (`omega` cannot be negative). This might have implications on the null distribution of the test statistic, making the regular $p$-value associated with the $t$-statistic inappropriate. There might be some relevant information in Francq & Zakoian ["Testing the nullity of GARCH coefficients: correction of the standard tests and relative efficiency comparisons"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2009.0117) (2009), but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: If you would provide me link to one of threads i would be very greatful

Comment: @Drac0, got you the thread I had in mind -- see the updated answer.

Comment: @Drac0, I have not actually given an explicit answer or solid reasoning, so you could wait for alternative answers before accepting. But in any case, I stand by my suggestion not to worry about this in practice, so you can still proceed with your analysis using the model you have.

Comment: ok i will wait for more answers.

Comment: Could you please tell me that i understood that article correct:

If someone will ask me about that insignicifant parameter i can answer something like:
If i drop intercept parameter other parameters will be biased, by leaving the intercept term im insure that the residual term is zero-mean.

Is that correct for my model? i know there in that article is all about regresion model

Comment: @Drac0, I cannot give you a definite answer. What I said is more about what is encouraged in practice but for this concrete model one would need to think hard and see how this can be justified. So I admit there is job to be done. And please delete your "answer" as it is not an answer, just a comment. Questions should be asked as proper questions (by opening a new thread), while clarifications can be solicited in comments.

Comment: Hmm... im fittin model to copper spot prices log returns. Theese returns are kinda low ... so maybe i can act like this is kinda normal here?

Comment: If you are looking at financial market data at a fairly high frequency (say, daily or higher), it's quite common to have insignificant mean return. In that context, the application is *rarely* long-term forecasting where fixing mean return = 0 would ruin the forecast, and doing so is a common practice. It may or may not be justified depending on the application.