# How should I interpret a non significant intercept in a GARCH model?

Tags: confidence-interval, garch, intercept

I am currently building a model based on a GARCH process. You can find a quick description of how the variance is modelled below.

$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \epsilon_{t-1}^2$,
$\epsilon_t = \sigma_t z_t$ where $z_t$ is a white noise process

Requirements are that $\alpha_0 >0, \alpha_i \geq 0,i>0$.

The current results show a confidence interval where the lower bound is negative and the upperbound is positive.
How should I interpret this lower bound given the requirements for the variance process? Should one prefer a model with a higher BiC score over this model, that is, is it problematic that the confidence interval contains zero? Note that I do not want to simply remove this intercept from the model but that I want to know its implications on the requirement that the intercept should be larger than 0.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It looks like this question may have been asked and answered before, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246113/what-to-do-with-an-insignificant-intercept-in-a-garch-model/246129#246129) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202493/should-i-keep-a-non-significant-intercept-in-a-garch-model). If these do not answer your question, please update it your question to explain why.

Comment: A word of caution: the confidence interval may very well have been generated by an incorrect procedure. The confidence intervals for parameters in GARCH models are rather complicated to estimate, so some software packages take shortcuts and end up with incorrect estimates.

Comment: @RichardHardy: How would one estimate the confidence interval? Right now I have simply made a confidence interval by using +-1.96*std but from your reply I read that this is an incorrect procedure?

Comment: I would have to look at the details to give a trustworthy answer, and I do not have time for that right now. However, you could check out Francq and Zakoian's book ["GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470670057) (2010), I think it includes a discussion of the distribution of (and confidence intervals for) parameter estimators in GARCH models.